# Access to `this` outside the scope of the method in class

Tags: javascript, class

I'm wondering why I can't have access to the parameter 'this.name' in the decorator of a method.

My code:

```js
class A {
  name: string;

  construct() {
    this.name = 'test';
  }

  @decorators(this.name)
  method() {}
}
```

In my decorator, I get a undefined.
I am missing something, I don't get it.
Can you help me up?
Thank you

Comment: `this` outside of your methods doesn't mean anything. what if you have multiple instances of the class? what should be `this` then? what do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: Decorators are evaluated at compiletime whereas this is a runtime variable

Comment: Thank you, I see now where was my problem, but I am still looking for a work around. What about I define a static function (attribut) and I re-evaluate it during the runtime in my constructor, then I execute the function in my decorator. It could be working. In fact, I define a empty function which returns nothing, then in the runtime, I overwrite the function.
`class A {
  func = () => {};

  construct() {
    this.func = () => 'test';
  }

  @decorators(this.func())
  method() {}
}`

Answer (score 0):

You start with an object syntax: `var C = { name: string; }` 
I created a snippet for you how to create a class and use the extend function.
Ask in the comments for an ES5 explanation.

```js
class A {
  constructor(param1, param2) {
    this.param1 = param1;
    this.param2 = param2;
  }
  
  // create a function
  get1() {
    return this.param1
  }
  
  set1(param1) {
    this.param1 = param1;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor(param1, param2, param3) {
    super(param1, param2); // Call A's constructor via super
    this.param3 = param3;
  }
  
  get3() {
    return this.param3
  }
  
  set3(param3) {
    this.param3 = param3;
  }
}

let a = new A(10, "foo"),
    b = new B(5, "doo", "lala");

console.log("--- A ---");

console.log("a.get1() : " + a.get1()); // read date from a
a.set1(3); // set a.param1 to 3
console.log("a.get1() : " + a.get1()); // read date from a

console.log("a.param2 : " + a.param2); // read date from a
a.param2 = 15; // set a.param2 to 15
console.log("a.param2 : " + a.param2); // read date from a

// add a variable to the a object
a.newvar = "new variable a";
console.log(a.newvar);

// add a function to the a object
a.newfunc = (param) => {
  return param;
}
console.log(a.newfunc("function a"));

console.log("--- B ---");

console.log("b.get1() : " + b.get1()); // read date from b
b.set1(3); // set b.param1 to 3
console.log("b.get1() : " + b.get1()); // read date from b

console.log("b.param2 : " + b.param2); // read date from b
b.param2 = 15; // set b.param2 to 15
console.log("b.param2 : " + b.param2); // read date from b

console.log("b.get3() : " + b.get3()); // read date from b
b.set3(3); // set b.param3 to 3
console.log("b.get3() : " + b.get3()); // read date from b

// the newvar is not given with object b
console.log(b.newvar);

// add a variable to the b object
b.newvar = "new variable b";
console.log(b.newvar);

// add a function to the b object
b.newfunc = (param) => {
  return param;
}
console.log(a.newfunc("function b"));
```

Comment: I did not include: `@decorators(this.name) method() {}` becouse it is ES7 and that is not implemented yet

Comment: Thank you for your help, but you are talking heritage, I can't see where this may help me up, because my main problem is I am trying to defined a runtime variable during the compilation. It's clearly impossible.

Comment: @Allan I edited the snippet I think that I added variables / functions to an object during runtime.